# C# compiler indicates a variable non-returnable ref variable when an out parameter is used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, struct, ref

C# compiler tells me the error written below when it's irrelevant.

> Cannot return 'entity' by reference because it was initialized to a value that cannot be returned by reference

I have a class named `SegmentedList`. Basically it's a wrapper for an array. I'll remove all logic and write the main method that I have the issue with:

```
 public sealed class UnorderedSegmentedList<TValue> : ISegmentedList where TValue : struct
    {
        private readonly int _arraySize;
        private List<Array> _arrayList = new List<Array>();
        public int ReservedValuesCount { get; private set; }

        public ref TValue Reserve(out int index)
        {
            var targetIndex = ReservedValuesCount;
            ReservedValuesCount++;
            var indices = CalculateIndices(targetIndex);
            var array = GetArray(indices.arrayIndex);
            index = indices.localItemIndex;
            return ref array[indices.localItemIndex];
        }

        private (int arrayIndex, int localItemIndex) CalculateIndices(int index)
        {
            return (index / _arraySize, index % _arraySize);
        }

        private TValue[] GetArray(int arrayIndex)
        {
            return (TValue[])_arrayList[arrayIndex];
        }
    }
```

So it happens when I'm using this class with a struct that I'm trying to pass by reference:

```
    public struct Entity
    {
        public readonly int Id;
    }

    public class Container
    {
        private readonly UnorderedSegmentedList<Entity> _entities;

        public ref Entity CreateEntity()
        {
            ref var entity = ref _entities.Reserve(out var index);
            entity = new Entity(index, _componentsContainer, new List<ComponentKey>());
            return ref entity;
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine if I remove the parameter **out int index** everywhere.
The variable int index is allocated in CreateEntity and it's not passed outside this method except Reserve. I don't understand how the variable is relative to struct. Is it a bug?

Comment: Which version of C# (the language, not .NET) are you using? Your code compiles on the latest version https://dotnetfiddle.net/IpDsZr but not on older versions https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xb3IWS I think the older versions are more cautious about returning `ref` which came from another function which may have been stack-allocated.

Comment: What is CalculateIndices() returning : var indices = CalculateIndices(targetIndex)?

Comment: @jdweng A tuple of `(int, int)`, it's in the question

Comment: @Charlieface :  _arraySize may not be set.

Comment: It's c# 9. It's the last supported version in unity and I can't upgrade it(.

Answer (score 1):

**It seems that this restriction only appears in certain versions of C#, earlier than version 11.**

Based on the rules of `ref return` [documented here](http://mustoverride.com/safe-to-return/):

> 6. a `ref`, returned from another method is safe to return if all `ref`s/`out`s passed to that method as formal parameters were safe to return.

In your case you are passing `out var index` which is unsafe to escape to the stack, therefore the returned `ref` from the function becomes unsafe also (even though you know this isn't a problem).

---

It seems this restriction has been relaxed in later versions of C#, as you can see from these two fiddles https://dotnetfiddle.net/IpDsZr and https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xb3IWS.

What has happened is that the `scoped` keyword has been introduced, from C# 11, which means that such parameters cannot be escaped out as a `return`. And `out` parameters are by default specified as `scoped`, therefore the compiler recognizes that it cannot escape the stack and therefore the function's return value as a whole is safe (because the `out` pointer could not have been returned). See [this GitHub document](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-11.0/low-level-struct-improvements.md#change-the-behavior-of-out-parameters), and [this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/low-level-struct-improvements).

Comment: Only found a [similar issue on GH](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/33072) which seems to be working fine with later compiler.

Comment: @GuruStron found it here https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-11.0/low-level-struct-improvements.md#change-the-behavior-of-out-parameters